# Reference multiple list items in single parentheses

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

How can I reference multiple list items, in a single parentheses, e.g. "(1-3)"?

For example, I have

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item \label{itm:1} more than 100
\item \label{itm:2} less than three
\item \label{itm:3} much less than ten
\end{enumerate}
```

How can I use `\ref` or something similar to reference items 1 through 3?

Answer (score 2):

Completely removing the intervening parentheses is potentially confusing and not easy to implement.  Placing a range marker automatically in between whilst retaining the parentheses is easy, using `cleveref`, and clearer:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefrangeformat{enumi}{items #3#1#4--#5#2#6}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
\item \label{itm:1} more than 100
\item \label{itm:2} less than three
\item \label{itm:3} much less than ten
\end{enumerate}

Referencing \cref{itm:1,itm:2,itm:3}.

\Cref{itm:1,itm:2} are just two items and \cref{itm:3} is another.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a separate `label` and `ref` for items via [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) which then allows you to construct your reference as needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*),ref=\arabic*]
  \item \label{itm:1} more than 100
  \item \label{itm:2} less than three
  \item \label{itm:3} much less than ten
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
See (\ref{itm:1}--\ref{itm:3}).

\end{document}
```